# MYSQL (Percona) Undo Log

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a usenet indexer running on a VM for my personal use only. And my hyper-visor OS drive died while everything was running.

Once I got it back up, the MYSQL database is running but I can't do anything with it because of a long running transaction:

`---TRANSACTION 39DD83, ACTIVE 9922 sec recovered trx
ROLLING BACK 1 lock struct(s), heap size 376, 1 row lock(s), undo log entries 21470928
---TRANSACTION 39DD83, ACTIVE 9922 sec recovered trx
ROLLING BACK 1 lock struct(s), heap size 376, 1 row lock(s), undo log entries 21470928
RECORD LOCKS space id 17 page no 1106 n bits 120 index "PRIMARY" of table "nzedb"."collections" trx id 39DD83 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap`

What this is telling me is that there are over 21million entries it has to run through. Is this necessary? Is there any way I can stop this without dropping the table or database?

Also, can anyone explain the purpose of the undo log? I haven't been able to find anything that looked useful.

FYI, I'm extremely new to SQL stuff.

Thanks.

Comment: if your transaction has 21 million individual sub-actions piled up in it, you really should rewrite the system to commit more often...

Comment: Marc's right, that would would here.  can you give your my.cnf settings?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/6QyWSHvv

The cnf was too long, I dropped it on pastebin for you.

Comment: Anything else guys? I'm not sure what I need to edit to prevent this while keeping the DB from bogging down.

Comment: So I've determined that it is a script that the indexer is running that is causing the massive amounts of entries to pile up without being committed. The particular script is https://github.com/nZEDb/nZEDb/blob/master/nzedb/Releases.php and the particular function is at line 1663, the Stage 7a. I'm going to hit up their forums to see if they can suggest anything.